# grakn grqal match query return less results than expected

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

The grakn server version is 1.3.0.

I have a 4000+ line CSV file, each line stands for an employee profile record. The CSV file has a column called Reportingline, which stands for the EmployeeID of the employee's line manage.

I can successfully migrate my CSV data into my Grakn keyspace, but when I use the following query I can only get one record returned.

```
match
$e isa employee has report-line "00136450";get;
```

[without 'contains' only 1 result returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUZJl.jpg)

The results are correct when I change the above query as below, but significantly this is a big performance hit.

```
match
$e isa employee has report-line contains "00136450";get;
```

[with 'contains' the result is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpf06.jpg)

Can anyone point out what is wrong with my query? How do I get the full results without *contains* keyword?

---

I use the following schema to define an employee

```
employee sub entity
plays superior
plays subordinate

has employee-id
has employee-name
has report-line
has bu
has email
has phone-number
has division
has title;

employee-id sub attribute datatype string;
employee-name sub attribute datatype string;
report-line sub attribute datatype string;
bu sub attribute datatype string;
email sub attribute datatype string;
phone-number sub attribute datatype string;
division sub attribute datatype string;
title sub attribute datatype string;
```

I use the following template to migrate the CSV data.

```
$x isa employee,
has employee-id <EmployeeID>,
has employee-name <EmployeeName>,
has report-line <ReportLine>,
if(<BU>!=null) do { has bu <BU>,}
has email <Email>,
if(<PhoneNumber>!=null) do { has phone-number <PhoneNumber>,}
if(<Division>!=null) do { has division <Division>,}
has title <Title>;
```

Comment: In your data, do you have multiple employees with `report-line` that is exactly equal to `00136450`?

Comment: Yes the CSV file does have multiple employees records have the same report-line value, for example, my manager has 9 direct report, in the CSV the 9 records have the same report-line values. Will this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue. I am writing here to confirm that the bug has been fixed in Grakn 1.4.0.